# Drupal 8 - Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

i received this error message when i was trying to install admin_menu in drupal 8 
can any one else help me to resolve this error ..

```
Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface in C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\drupal-8\core\lib\Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php on line 268
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the known error in Drupal port and needs work.

```
variable_set('admin_menu_cache_client', FALSE);
```

variable_set is depreciated in Drupal8.

Details of the issue can be found at:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2563867